# Android - Sending data from an activity to a service

Tags: android, service, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've a local service that is started in my main activity. The service is responsible for network I/O. It also interacts with other activities in my application. Till, now the service was only "providing" data to activity (using callbacks and not Intents.)

Now I need to send data (custom objects) from my activities to the service. I understand one way to do it using Intents. I know it is possible to receive an Intent in the service by overriding the `onStartCommand()` in my service. But it's not clear to me if the onStartCommand will be invoked every time I broadcast an Intent from my sending activity. Can a Service also be `BroadcastReceiver` ? If yes - how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a BroadcastReceiver object in the service and register it to listen to any broadcast event you want. It's something like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver mScreenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //handle the broadcast event here
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, filter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
}
```

Regards,